# How do I find the cpu wattage that my motherboard can supply

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a gigabyte motherboard (ga-f2a78m-hd2) fm2+ socket , 500w psu and I want to upgrade my cpu.

Current cpu: a6-7400k

New cpu: a10-7850k

The current cpu uses 65w an the cpu I want to upgrade to requires 95w.

Is there a way to find if my motherboard can support/supply 95w?

Edit: 
I have not bought the new cpu yet.
Are there any cpu better than a10-7850k that is under £200.
Can anyone direct me to a website for cheap/low cost cpu fans for the a10 cpu?

Comment: Yes, this fits amd A10.

Comment: There are 2 questions really. 1) Will my socket & chipset support A10? Yes. 2) Is my power supply up to the job? Depends on the wattage, but most likely unless you have other devices draining a lot of power. Note that your termps will likely go up, so make sure you have good venitlation. You'll likely want a better HSF too. I wouldn't skimp on a cheap stock HSF, i'd go for a decent brand such as a BeQuiet! Dark Rock or something similar https://www.bequiet.com/en/cpucooler/479

Comment: @spikey_richie . Thank you this has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your motherboard is indicated as compatible in the PC Part Picker website:
[A10-7850K 3.7 GHz Quad-Core Compatible Motherboards](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/motherboard/?compatible_with=amd-cpu-ad785kxbjabox):

[image]

The difference between 65w and 95w is not large enough to matter for the PSU,
unless the existing devices already take all that it can give
(somewhat unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

Gigabyte list it on their [CPU Support page](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-F2A78M-HD2-rev-30/support#support-cpu) as being compatible and needing 95W:

[image]

**Please note that you need BIOS version `F1` or later.**

PSU *should* be ok if you're only running a single GPU and not overclocking (much)
(What GPU are you using?)